Rounded borders on selection of PlainListStyle() in SwiftUI macOS
I try to get rid of the paddings in a List on SwiftUI. I tried some different ways like using negative paddings or negative EdgeInsets:
struct ListView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: self.$selection) {
            ForEach([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], id: \.self) { item in
                Text("This is item \(item)")
            }
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -10, leading: -10, bottom: -10, trailing: -10))
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListView()
}

This doesn't help, because it will not show the scroll indicator anymore.
If I set the trailing EdgeInset to 0, the scroll indicator will be shown again, but it start vertically negative:

The only way to get rid of the padding then is using .listStyle(.plain)
Unfortunately, the selection of the items then don't have a cornerRadius anymore:

But I want to have a cornerRadius again like when using .listStyle(.inset). This is when using negative EdgeInset:

Any ideas?
